# Options for developing 3D Web App

Tags: silverlight, flash, 3d, webgl

I am developing a webapp which the most challenging aspect is the 3D model section. It also contains other things such as drag and drop and a sliding bar with arrows each side which the user can go through to select different items.

I have been looking into `WebGL` but it seems IE doesn't support it without using a plugin. This isn't ideal so I was wondering what other options I have.

Flash? Silverlight? Anything else?

Comment: Maybe [Ajax3D](http://ajax3d.sourceforge.net/). Not much experience with it myself though.

Comment: Sadly, I think that the only tested viable option is a java applet.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum There is Java3D, but that requires signing the applet.

Comment: @S.L.Barth.. checked it out but that won't work in IE as it uses the html5 canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is WAY too rare to be used for any meaningful development, and ajax is simply not stunning enuogh. That leaves us with Flash, which in my opinion, is the best of the three options. Flash Player 11 introduces the new [Stage3D API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html) which can create pretty stunning 3D graphics. There are also many AS3 libraries for 3D rendering. I prefer [Away3D](http://away3d.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Just found this, which looks promising.

http://iewebgl.com/

**Edit:** Disregard, seems the user has to download the executable for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

at the moment flash is most popular plugin for 3D based web apps. which is cross browser, but no mobile browsers support :(
Many technologies and every one have his disatvantages